# Use separate bundle for images

Tags: ios, objective-c, resources, image-loading

I'm making a game app. That games has many about 450 images. Some images are just small png icons and about 100 of them are jpg, about 43 KB size. App work fine but it takes a lot of time to start. But sometimes it crash on iPhone 4 on app launch.

My question is - Should I use separate bundle for images? Would there be any benefit?
What is the benefit of using multiple bundles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Images are loaded lazily when you first draw them. It makes no difference where you store them in your app resources.

Depending on how they are used, you may reduce memory pressure by loading images using +imageWithContentsOfFile: instead of +imageNamed:, as the former does not cache decoded images once they are no longer being used (this may make performance worse as a consequence however).